# Python, ML: препроцессинг данных для predict

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение

Данные для train проходят предварительную обработку (нормализацию/стандартизацию или т.п.)
Однако модуль predict -- для этой же ml-модели -- находится отдельно, и нет возможности провести предварительную подготовку данных для predict на основе величин из train-датасета (std и дисперсия для standart scaler, max значение для maxabs scaler и т.п.)
На данный момент я пока делаю так -- обучаю модель на стандартизированных данных, но делаю predict на НЕ-стандартизированных данных.
Вопрос: как лучше поступить с точки зрения best practise? Да, и вообще, является ли это -- обучение модели на стандартизированных данных, но predict на НЕ стандартизированных -- значимой ошибкой?

Answer (score 1):

*Да, и вообще, является ли это -- обучение модели на стандартизированных данных, но predict на НЕ стандартизированных -- значимой ошибкой?*  -  да, в общем случае это ошибка, которая не позволит получить вразумительные результаты.

И да, если обучить на стандартизованных данных и подать стандартизованные-же данные, то чаще всего результат будет лучше, чем если обучать и использовать не стандартизованные.
Но это не имеет отношения к схеме "учим на стандартизованных, подаем нестандартизованные", которая всегда ущербна.

Если вы (например) используете сторонний модуль, который выполняет predict, то очевидно либо он сам должен иметь средства для стандартизации ваших данных, либо дать вам такой метод, что-бы принять от вас уже стандартизованные данные. Иначе все как-то очень странно и урывчато.

Comment: Спасибо. Поправлю вас лишь в том, что я писал о лучшем результате именно при подаче НЕ-стандартизированных данных в модель, обученную на стандартизированных (нежели при обучении на НЕ-стандартизированных и подаче снова НЕ-стандартизированных же). В противном случае я бы и не задал этого вопроса -- а сразу отказался бы от стандартизации, в принципе.

Comment: Я думаю автор всё же ищет некое математическое подкрепление ваших выводов. Предполагается, что он уже знаком с предобработкой и пытается понять, "насколько" хуже/лучше будут результаты, если в train стадии он будет использовать обработку, а в продакшене - нет. Что это ошибка - это понятно, на сколько значима - нет, что и является вторым вопросом автора

Comment: Да, все верно. Спасибо за ваше пояснение. Собственно моя тревога и родилась из того, что фактически ошибочный подход -- обучение на стандартизированных, но predict на НЕ-стандартизированных -- дает лучший результат, нежели отказ от стандартизации, в принципе. Это мне показалось любопытным и заслуживающим публичного вопроса :)

Comment: @derdentyler Если описанный вами подход даёт лучший результат, то это может объясняться разными причинами. Например, что данные, на которых делается предсказание, ближе к стандартизированным, а тренировочные - наоборот. Или что есть какие-то выбросы в тренировочных данных, которые несколько нивелируются стандартизацией. Нужно смотреть конкретные данные, но вообще кейс интересный, если всё так. Не удивлюсь также, если окажется, что стандартизация всё же делается при предикте, просто вы об этом не знаете. )  Раз вы не имеете полного контроля над процессом, там может оказаться что угодно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Стандартизация для predict не проводится точно. Поскольку у меня нет всех scale коэффициентов, чтобы ее проводить. По сути, вопрос сводится к подобию этого https://question-it.com/questions/563925/kak-sohranit-parametry-masshtabirovanija-dlja-posledujuschego-ispolzovanija, с той лишь разницей, что пока нет объективно лучшего способа передать эти коэффициенты для predict модуля

Answer (score 1):

В вашей постановке задачи слишком много неизвестных:

1. Данные по своей природе могут быть уже близки к стандартизированным, тогда особой разницы не будет, стандартизируют их перед отправкой в модель или нет
2. Используемые модели тоже влияют. Деревья могут привязываться к конкретным промежуткам величин входных данных, в результате при подаче в деревянную модель обработанных и необработанных данных вы можете получить кардинально разные результаты. А если у вас простая линейная регрессия - ну, ок, результат будет сдвинут, угол наклона линии регрессии будет другой, но, в принципе, это и правда может быть поправимо постобработкой, если подгадать параметры.

Естественно, единственный совет, который тут можно дать, если вы не можете контролировать обработку данных для predict - это обучать модель на необработанных данных. Тогда получаемый результат будет наиболее релевантен. Но в любом случае по-хорошему нужно изучать данные, смотреть, как на них влияет обработка, как на них учится модель и т.д. А так пока это сферические данные в вакууме, про то, как ведёт себя ваша модель в таких условиях, можно только гадать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Тип моей задачи регрессионный. Использую разные алгоритмы, включая нейронные сети. Линейную регрессию также пробую, но, скорее, в качестве шутки. Данные по своей природе не стандартизированные, но по разбросу значений -- различаются не сильно трагично. С вашим советом -- однозначно согласен. Так, видимо, и поступлю. При этом было просто любопытно как другие решали сходные задачи, когда из-за локазизованности каждого модуля не было прямой возможности передать коэффициенты стандартизации для преобработки данных на predict

Comment: @derdentyler Ну, обычно такой проблемы просто нет. Это очень странно, что вы можете передать в продакшен натренированную модель, но не можете контролировать сам процесс обучения и в частности предобработку данных. Обычно есть контроль над всем процессом внедрения модели. А вместо стандартизации лучше тогда: 1) отобрать модели, устойчивые к выбросам/разбросу данных, 2) делать тот или иной стэкинг/блендинг нескольких моделей, чтобы "усреднить" их данные и таким образом опять же нивелировать выбросы в данных.

Comment: С большего с вами согласен. Формально, проблема в том, что на локализованный train модуль я передаю список фичей (признаков), сгенерированный из первоначального датасета. С локализованным же модулем predict модуль train может взаимодействовать, например, посредством базы данных. Но перебрасывать через нее, например, все коэффициенты стандартизации -- не самая лучшая идея (она, скажем так, предназначена для иных данных). Хотя, по сути, я вижу два варианта решения проблемы: либо отказаться от стандартизации в принципе, либо действительно перекидывать список коэффициентов через базу.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу только на первый вопрос: как вариант, использовать ml-алгоритмы, которые инвариантны к предобработке, например алгоритмы на деревьях: DecisionTree, RF, бустинги

Comment: Спасибо. Разумеется, на данных алгоритмах все работает хорошо, однако, в первую очередь, интересуют именно регрессионные модели. Например, тот же LGBM -- обученный на стандартизированных данных -- при predict на НЕ стандартизированных данных дает лучший результат, чем обученный на НЕ стандартизированных. Поэтому меня и интересует, в первую очередь, сходный опыт коллег в данном вопросе. В любом случае -- спасибо!

Comment: То что алгоритмы инвариантны к предобработке, это означает, что они могут обучаться и работать и со стандартизацией и без, и она не сильно влияет на эффективность. Но это никак не означает, что можно обучать на стандартизованных, а использовать - нестандартизованные данные.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен. Поэтому я пробрасывал в predict модуль максимальное значение target из train модуля (при тренировке использовал maxabs scale), чтобы потом перевести predict значение в адекватные величины. Однако при этом у меня нет возможности передать в predict максимальные значения остальных признаков из train модуля, чтобы провести обработку данных. Иначе говоря, вышло так: я обучал модель на стандартизированных данных, после получал стандартизированный predict на НЕ-стандартизированных данных, и переводил его домножением на максимальное значение. И это меня тревожит :)

Comment: я отвечал на первый вопрос автора :) в продакшн среде, я бы использовал те алгоритмы, которые подходя задаче с учётом входных параметров (отсутсвие возможности обработки на этапе предикта), а не те, которые хочется, так как мы снижаем риск выстрела в ногу.

Answer (score 0):

Больше спасибо за ответы.
Итак: 1.) делать predict на НЕ-стандартизированных данных, если модель обучалась на стандартизированных однозначно хорошим делом не назовут 2.) то, что в подобном случае я получил лучший скор, нежели использование НЕ-стандартизированного датасета и для train, и для predict, по всей видимости было вызвано относительно небольшим разбросом значений исходных данных.
На данный момент рассматриваю два равнозначных решения проблемы: либо отказаться от стандартизации, в принципе, либо же перебрасывать scale коэффициенты от одного локализованного модуля к другому через базу данных (иных способов в моем случае нет).